# Trying to select a list item within an unordered list with another unordered list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors

The problem i am running into is that clicking on a nested list item is the same as clicking the lit item that list was listed under. so if i were to try a console.log the list item clicked on using jscript and i clicked on one of the nested list items with in a list i would get two console.logs. the first one being the actual list item object you clicked on and the second log would be the list item holding the unordered list. Any way to get around this?

Basically i want the user to be able to click on the list item that has a drop-down and the page gets loaded as well as makes the drop-down list pull down. when you click on any of the nested list items in the drop-down the content gets loaded from that link and then the drop-down menu gets hidden.

Please any help on getting around this would be very helpful.

Here is HTML

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="toggle-btn visible-xs"><i class="fa fa-sort-desc fa-2x"></i></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active-menu" attr="Retirementplans2" href="">Retirement Plans</a></li>
            <li class="exty"><a  class="nact subm" attr="nadart4kplans" href="">NADART 401(k) Plans<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a class="nact sub" attr="investmentChoicePlans" href="">Investment Choice Plans</a></li>
                <li><a class="nact sub" attr="openArchitecturePlans" href="">Open Architecture Plans</a></li>
                <li><a class="nact sub" attr="nadartsub20plans" href="">Sub20 Plans</a></li>
                <li><a class="nact sub" attr="executiveplansolutions" href="">Executive Plan Solutions</a></li>
                </ul></li>
                <li class="exty"><a class="nact subm" attr="PlanDesign" href="">Plan Design<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a class="nact sub" attr="flexiblefreestructure" href="">Flexible Fee Structure</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nact sub" attr="EmployerMatchingOptions" href="">Employer Matching Options</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nact sub" attr="AutomaticEnrollment" href="">Automatic Enrollments</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nact sub" attr="Roth4kOption" href="">Roth 401(k) Option</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nact sub" attr="rai" href="">Retirement Accumulation Insurance</a></li>
                    </ul></li>
                    <li><a class="nact" attr="Fiduciaryservices" href="">Feduciary Services</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nact" attr="Understanding4kFees" href="">Understanding 401(k) Plans</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nact" attr="Makinga4kDecision" href="">Making 401(k) Decision</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nact" attr="MakingTheTransitionEasy" href="">Making the Transition Easy</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Here is the script:

```
var submenu = function(){
var tglBtn = $(".toggle-btn"),
    mc = $(".main-content"),
    subnav = $(".sub-menu"),
    subItem = $(".menu ul").find('li');
if(tglBtn.css('display') === 'block'){
    $(".menu ul").find('li.nact').slideToggle();
}
tglBtn.on('click', function(){
    $(".menu ul").find('li.nact').slideToggle();
});
if($(".toggle-btn").css('display') === 'block'){
    subItem.on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".menu ul").find('li.nact').hide();
    });
}
if(subnav.length >= 1){
    subnav.find('li').hide();
}
var submenuNavigation = {
    ajaxCall: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this),
            pageName = $this.attr('attr').toLowerCase(),
            item = '_'+pageName+'.html',
            subMenu = $this.find('ul').length;
            $this.parent().find('li').removeClass('actLink');
            console.log(item);
            if($this.hasClass("subm")){
                $this.next('ul').find('li').show();
                $this.next('ul').find('a').show();
            }
            $.ajax('partials/'+item, {
                url:location.pathname+pageName+' - NADART',
                success: function(response){
                    mc.html(response);
                    $this.addClass('actLink');
                    location.hash = pageName;
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("Page not available");
                },
                beforeSend: function(){
                    mc.addClass('.loading');
                },
                complete: function(){
                    mc.removeClass('.loading');
                }
            });//END OF AJAX CALL
    },
    subnav: function(){
        //subnav.find('li').toggle();
    }
};

//EVENTS
subItem.on('click', 'a', submenuNavigation.ajaxCall);
subnav.on('click', 'a', submenuNavigation.subnav);
};


$(document).ready(function(){
    submenu();
    mainItem();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this:

1. load your content asynchronously so that the menu stays on the page in it's current state

or

2. save your menu state to a cookie so that it can be restored when the page reloads

Comment: The content is being loaded asynchronously. The problem is that when i select one of the dropdown links i am getting the console.log for that link and the list item that it is under. So it only loads the initial dropdown link button content instead of the dropdown link content if that makes since.

Comment: Basically if i were to console.log the object being clicked and i click on one of the dropdown lis items i get two logs to the console: the first one being the initial link that was click(dropdown link) and the list item object that is holding the dropdwon list.

Comment: What code are you using for the listeners? If you are using jQuery.click() then  maybe you just need preventDefault() and/or stopPropagation() functions on the event.

Comment: Hey, Mark i added the script to the initial question, hope this helps. thank you for taking your time to help me out.

Comment: So basically the script grabs the attr="pagename" and parses it so it i can uses it as a tag to use ajax and load in the content.

Comment: Check out this video to see what the problem is visually.http://travismichael.net/listScript.mp4

Comment: Try adding e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation() to both your ajaxCall and subnav functions. If that doesn't work then separate your menu levels by adding different class names to your li tags such as 'primary', 'secondary' - you can then add your listeners to each individually.